# My Windows 7 RC screensaver and DPMI power off functions have ceased to work. How can I fix them?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, mac, screensaver

My screensaver in my Windows 7 RC just doesn't get activated, no matter what timeout I put. Even the power saving feature does't put the monitor to sleep.

This only happens in Windows. If I reboot into Mac OS X (I'm using an iMac), the screensaver there works just fine and so does the sleep mode. It's just Windows 7 RC.

I've never had this kind of a problem with any OS before. I have been unable to find any info by just Googling. The simplest solution is to simply reinstall the RC, but I've got a bunch of things set up in a particularly and I don't want to go through all that again.

Does anyone know of any config entries that may have "hard disabled" the screensaver/sleep timeout? Any files that I can try replacing?

Another thing. Since this is an iMac, there's no way to turn the LCD off other than the sleep mode. So every night, I need to put a big piece of cloth on the LCD before I go to bed! LOL

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `powercfg -requests` into a command prompt to see whether any of your applications have requested the display to be active.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try running Boot Camp again or a newer version, since I suspect you lack the drivers to run the advanced power settings/screen saver. Perhaps best to try the latest video card drivers as well.

Edit: after some searching I think you'll have to wait till the next version of Boot Camp

Comment: It was working fine for a long time. This just started happening recently. I haven't updated the Mac firmware or anything, so it's unlikely that anything like that could have broken Windows...

Comment: I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and installed Boot Camp 3.0 in my Windows 7, but the problem persists. I think I'll just have to reinstall the damn thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found peculiar behaviour on Windows 7 RC1 on a 24" iMac, with the screen saver not working sometimes.

Things to look at:

- Check that something like iTunes, Media Player or VLC hasn't been running. They have a setting to disable your screensaver.
- Test whether the screen saver can be activated when you first turn on.
- Check your advanced power settings as well for your power plan.